# Custom serialize part of a POJO using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I have a POJO for example like this:

```
class SurveyResult {
   public String name;
   public List<QuestionAnswer> questions;
}
class QuestionAnswer {
   public String key;
   public String question;
   public boolean answer;
}
```

I get the list of questions from the server so I don't know beforehand what they might be. When sending the `SurveyResult` back up to the server I need to send the following Json:

```
{ "name": "John Doe", "question1key" : true, "question2key" : false }
```

As you can see the list of `QuestionAnswer` is flattened to the same level as the `SurveyResult.name`. When building a custom serializer how can I achieve this? I know I can possibly do it by custom serializing the entire `SurveyResult` object but in the real world case there may be a lot of fields and I don't want to have to custom serialize all those fields just to flatten the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want Gson, disregard this answer. Here I implemented a solution using [Oson serializer and jsonNoName, requires 1.0.8](https://github.com/osonus/oson/blob/master/src/test/java/ca/oson/json/listarraymap/SurveyResultTest.java)